# How to hide the robots.txt file for SharePoint internet facing sites

Tags: 2013, 2016

how to hide the robots.txt file for internet facing sites, it will show the users sitemap file, but search engine optimization will work if I hide this file.

Answer (score 1):

I think based on the **Search engine sitemap settings** feature disabled or enabled we can show or hide the **robots.txt** file. However, if we want to restrct certain types of files, we can add the entry to the file as like below:

User-agent: *

Disallow: /_layouts/

Disallow: /_vti_bin/

Disallow: /_catalogs/

If you want you to want to allow SharePoint 2010 or 2013 to crawl your web site add the following to your robots.txt file.

User-agent: **MS Search 6.0 Robot**

Disallow:

Source:

[The right robots.txt settings for allowing SharePoint to crawl your site](https://www.techmikael.com/2014/12/the-right-robotstxt-settings-for.html)

Comment: Is robots.txt file used by internally by SharePoint Search or is it used by Search engline optimization externally